# Python- using odeint with two equations

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to plot Temperature over a length of time (1800 sec). I have two initial value problems, where func2 depends on func1 and two initial values.

Here are the two functions:

```
rate = dA/dt = -(3.083e8*np.exp(-56000/(8.314*Temp))*A*0.033) 

dT/dt = (-0.45*-98000*rate+5.7431*(273.15-Temp))/(2018.94)
```

where A is the concentration of a substance and Temp is the temperature.

My initial values are:

```
T[0]=281.15
A[0]=6.529
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t = np.linspace(0,1800,100) #timeline
c0 = np.array([281.15,6.529]) #initial values

def df(c, t):
    Temp = c[0]
    A = c[1]
    rate = -(3.083e8*np.exp(-56000/(8.314*Temp))*A*0.033)
    dTdt = (-0.45*-98000*rate+5.7431*(273.15-Temp))/(2018.94)
    return np.array([dTdt, rate])

sol = odeint(df, c0, t)
plt.plot(t, sol)
```

It just generates [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttJZz.png) which is wrong. It should look like the upper curve in this figure: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPo43.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You swapped around the coordinates in the result of df.  It should be: `return np.array([dTdt,rate])`

Comment: Also, the expression `exp(-56000/(8.314*Temp))` underflows to 0 when `Temp` is 8.  What are the units of `Temp`?  The Arrhenius equation requires the temperature in kelvins.

Comment: switched return results and changed initial Temp to Kelvin (was in Celsius) still getting an incorrect graph...

Comment: Do you have a reference for these equations and for the expected graph?

Comment: Check that you have properly converted the differential equations to Python code.  Check the values and signs of all the constants.  To get the upper curve in the graph that you show, dT/dt at t=0 must be positive, but with your code and initial values, `df(c0, 0)` returns `array([-0.0799149 , -0.00261675])`, which means that both the temperature and concentration are *decreasing* at t=0.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a sign error in the equation for dT/dt.  When I changed it to

```
dTdt = (0.45*-98000*rate + 5.7431*(273.15-Temp))/(2018.94)
```

I got the curve that you expected.

Here's a modified version of your code, and the resulting plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t = np.linspace(0, 1800, 901)    # timeline
c0 = np.array([281.15, 6.529])  # initial values

def df(c, t):
    Temp = c[0]
    A = c[1]
    rate = -(3.083e8*np.exp(-56000/(8.314*Temp))*A*0.033)
    dTdt = (0.45*-98000*rate + 5.7431*(273.15 - Temp))/(2018.94)
    return np.array([dTdt, rate])

sol = odeint(df, c0, t)
plt.plot(t, sol[:,0] - 273.15)
plt.xlabel('t (sec)')
plt.ylabel('T (degrees C)')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]